# Shell command to bring a program window in front of another?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, command-line

Does a shell command exist to bring a already started program in gnome in the front of another.

i.e.:

Gedit and Nautilus are started.
Nautilus is in the background and Gedit in the foreground.

How to i bring Nautilus in the front with a shell command?

Comment: Other: http://superuser.com/questions/183680/gnome-ubuntu-how-to-bring-a-program-window-to-the-front-using-a-command-line-f

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37258/113056 has some good answers (one of mine as well) that use `xdotool` to focus a window before sending it a key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Install [**wmctrl** [image: Install wmctrl]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl)

  `wmctrl -a <name>`
- You can also use [**xdotool** [image: Install xdotool]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)

**Note:**

- More information about xdotool can be found **[here](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)**.

Comment: Sure edit your post just as I'm composing mine... :( )

Comment: You can find your window name with 
wmctrl -l
The name is the text after the last dash:
<window ID> <desktop ID> <client machine> <window title>

Answer (score 9):

Another option is [xdotool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xdotool):

`xdotool search --class Nautilus windowactivate`

Comment: Fails for me with `XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)`

Comment: Probably the bug [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/semicomplete/issues/66) -- in my experience --classname or --name (if known) works sometimes when --class doesn't.

Comment: In my case it was possible to raise a window using the ID from `xwininfo` and issuing several additional different `xdotool` commands (which I no more remember).  When I tried to automate that (to get rid of `xwininfo`) I got visual artifacts due to otherwise hidden windows which were selected, too.  I simply found no generic way to address arbitrary windows correctly.  After switching to `wmctrl -a` everything immediately worked flawlessly out of the box without any further tweaking.  Please note that I like `xdotool`, but it seems to be difficult to raise just the correct window with it.

Comment: `xdotool search --desktop 0 Nautilus windowactivate` did it for me

Answer (score 3):

When using [`xdotool`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool), it seems difficult to bring to front *all* windows for a given application or class using only one command. I end up having better results by wrapping it in a `for` loop at the shell level. Using Bash:

```
for WINDOW in $(xdotool search --desktop 0 Firefox); do
   xdotool windowactivate ${WINDOW}
done
```

Few remarks:

- By default, `xdotool search` will search the pattern (here `Firefox`) in window name, class, and classname. If you want to restrict your search space, use the relevant `--class`, `--name` or `--classname` options.
- The `--desktop 0` option limits the search to the first desktop. This seems to be a workaround to avoid the `XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)` mentioned in some comments.
- At the time of this writing, the `xdotool` project is stalled since 2015. It still remains my tool of choice though. For personal reasons, Jordan Sissel (the original author) is not as active as he was, so don't hesitate to contribute to the project.

Comment: If you want to bring up all the windows of an application, instead of a for loop you can use `%@` which applies it to all windows. Also, you'll want --onlyvisible option to avoid fake or invisible windows. For example, `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class firefox windowactivate %@` will bring up every firefox window. If you omit `%@`, you'll only get the first one. You can choose which one you want by changing @ to a positive integer such as `%2`. Make sure you remember the `--onlyvisible`, especially if you don't use `%@` or you probably won't get any windows.